# Perl - push rows into an array

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, perl-data-structures

I found a lib on CPAN,  named Statistics-MVA-MultipleRegression-0.0.1,

[the library's link is here](http://search.cpan.org/~dsth/Statistics-MVA-MultipleRegression-0.0.1/lib/Statistics/MVA/MultipleRegression.pm)

The coding example is like this:

```
use Statistics::MVA::MultipleRegression;   
my $lol = [

        [qw/745  36  66/],
        [qw/895  37  68/],
        [qw/442  47  64/],
        [qw/440  32  53/],
        [qw/1598 1   101/],
     ];

    my ($Array_ref_of_coefficients, $R_sq) = linear_regression($lol);
```

but the array $lol, I'd like to push some rows at RUNTIME, not initial it,

says:

---

```
 my $input = [$x, $y, $z];

 push @tmpArray, $input;

 my $lol = \@tmpArray;
```

---

but this is not working, could anyone give me  some way to get this right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say "this is not working", can you be more specific? What is not working? How is it not working? Are there specific errors you are getting or are the results from linear_regression() just not as expected?

Answer (score 2):

Push it like this, `$lol` is a array reference containing array references and you want to push one more array refernce.

```
push(@{$lol}, $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

To populate the array at runtime, your code will have structure similar to the code below, assuming you are reading input from a file.

```
my $lol = [];

open my $fh, "<", "input.dat" or die "$0: open: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my($x,$y,$z) = split;

    push @$lol, [$x, $y, $z];
}
```

From there, call `linear_regression` on the matrix in `$lol`.